# jasmine-node async doesn't understand code errors

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

I am trying jasmine-node with async :

```
it('should not be dumb', function(done){
Promise.resolve(0).then(function(){
  console.log('dumb');
  expect(2).toEqual(2);
  done();
});
```

});

returns :

```
dumb
.

Finished in 0.026 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 0 failures, 0 skipped
```

But somehow, if I have an error in my code:

```
  it('should not be dumb', function(done){
  Promise.resolve(0).then(function(result){
    console.log('dumb');
    expect(2,toEqual(2));
    done();
    }, function (err){console.log(err); done()});
  });
```

It just sits there until it times out, without any useful output:

```
dumb

Pairing user stories - 7816 ms
    should not be dumb - 7815 ms

Failures:

  1) Pairing user stories should not be dumb    Message:
     timeout: timed out after 5000 msec waiting for spec to complete    Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 46.884 seconds 1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 skipped
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you access err with `Promise.resolve(0).then(function(err){
  console.log(err);`?

Comment: No. I updated the question and added error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume this:

```
promise.then(onResolve, onReject)
```

`onReject` will be called when `promise` is rejected. However, in your code, the rejection happens in `onResolve` (implicitly, by an error being thrown), which doesn't affect `promise` (which has already been resolved at that point) and hence will not call `onReject`.

If you want to catch errors being thrown in an `onResolve`, you need to handle them by adding another rejection handler to your promise chain:

```
Promise.resolve(0).then(function(result){
  console.log('dumb');
  expect(2,toEqual(2));
  done();
}).then(null, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  done()
});
```

If `Promise` happens to be `bluebird`, you can shorten it somewhat by using `.catch()`:

```
Promise.resolve(0).then(function(result){
  console.log('dumb');
  expect(2,toEqual(2));
  done();
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  done()
});
```

Comment: Thanks Robert! I wish there was a way for jasmine to catch it. It is a bummer to add that to all my tests.

Comment: @Arash I'm not very familiar with Jasmine, but it looks similar to [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/), which has promise support built in.